# how can i check how website storing password in database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have to create a simple php page which update user's password in database, i've to enter password in same encrypted format in which website storing it in. I don't know much about working of laravel. Password stored in database is "$2y$10$pFYa/ruRVbDbr9KJs67XLOLXg6XNo9t8hkREI/xyAR54/42HO7zXC" which is "Freelance" in actual. How can i find out how it's encrypting "Freelance" to this format so that I can also store new password in database in similar format. Thanks!

Comment: have you ever heard of bscrypt hash algorithm which is based on blowfish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's storing the hash in the database as `bcrypt` with 10 rounds.

`$2y$`represents bcrypt and `10$` shows 10 rounds.

Use the `password_hash` function in PHP e.g. `password_hash("password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => 10]);`

Alternatively, there are a few sites which you can use e.g:

- http://fipi.ch/php-online/hash-bcrypt.php
- http://aspirine.org/htpasswd_en.html